# Using filter with pipe, getting error on length of result

Tags: r

I want to select the "clarity" of each diamond, where the `cut == "Premium"`

I have the following code:

```
> (dia <- select(diamonds, clarity, cut) %>% 
          filter(dia, cut == "Premium"))
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Error: Result must have length 53940, not 107880
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.ordered(left, right) : '&' is not meaningful for ordered factors
2: In Ops.ordered(left, right) : '&' is not meaningful for ordered factors
```

Thanks for any guidence

Comment: Drop the  "dia" argument in the filter function

Comment: Just `... %>% filter(cut == 'Premium')`. No need to redefine your data frame. You already do at the beginning of the pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to pass the data object when using pipes:

```
dia <- select(ggplot2::diamonds, clarity, cut) %>%
         filter(cut == "Premium")
```

Or even clearer:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
dia <- diamonds %>%
       select(clarity, cut) %>%
       filter(cut == "Premium")
```